# Jquery datetime picker not working with the masterpage

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

the jquery datepicker is not work in usercontrol through the masterpage....struggling a lot.....

masterpage

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MasterPage.master.cs" Inherits="MasterPage" %>
    <%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head runat="server">
    <title>Master Page</title>
    <link href="App_Themes/LMSTheme/Style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../App_Themes/LMSTheme/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>

    <script src="Scripts/ui.datepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <style>.Hide{ display:none;}</style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div class="divcontent">
            <table width="100%">
                <tr height="400px" valign="top">
                    <td width="10px">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="WorkArea" runat="server">
                        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my usercontrol:

```
 <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="HRApproveSwipeLeave.ascx.cs"
    Inherits="HRApproveSwipeLeave" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../App_Themes/LMSTheme/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/ui.datepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#txtDate').datepicker({changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true});
    });
</script>

<div class="demo">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
```

This is the aspx while i call thourgh the master page.....

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Theme="LMSSkinFile" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" CodeFile="HRApprovSwipeLeave.aspx.cs" Inherits="HRApprovSwipeLeave" Title="ApproveSwipeLeave"%>
<%@ Register Src="UserControl/HRApproveSwipeLeave.ascx" TagName="HRApproveSwipeLeave" TagPrefix="LMS" %>
<asp:Content ID="LMS_HRApproveSwipeLeave" ContentPlaceHolderID="WorkArea" runat="Server">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <contenttemplate>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="BoldCopy">
                <asp:Label ID="WelcomeUserName" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:Label>                
            </td>
        </tr>       
    </table>
    <table> 
        <tr>
            <td>                
               <asp:Label ID="ApproveSwipeLeave" Font-Bold=true ForeColor=red runat="server"></asp:Label>      
            </td>
        </tr>  
        <tr>
            <td>                
                <LMS:HRApproveSwipeLeave ID="LMSHRApproveSwipeLeave" runat="server" />  
            </td>
        </tr>
           </table>
       </contenttemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Content>
```

Note:the jquery time picker when i run through the user control it is not firing at all..if i create a sample aspx and do it is working....i do no where to change the code either in the masterpage or ascx or aspx..for your reference i have send the three.please help to resolve...i am digging a lot with this.....

Comment: have you verified that your document.ready() is getting called?

Comment: ya the pblm is in the master page of calling the jquery

Comment: you said, "if i create a sample aspx and do it is working". could you post the "sample aspx"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

code below is working for me.

**Master Page**

```
<head runat="server">
<%--JQUERY--%>

<link rel = "Stylesheet" href ="../jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom/development-bundle/demos/demos.css" />
<link rel = "Stylesheet" href ="../jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom/development-bundle/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css" />

<script language="javascript" src="script.js"> </script>

<script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.6.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<%--JQUERY--%>
```

**Client Page**

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="maincontent" Runat="Server">
    <script type ="text/javascript">
        $(function () {

            $("#<%= txtDate.ClientID  %>").datepicker();

        });

    </script> 

        <div id ="divname">

            <asp:TextBox ID = "txtDate" runat ="server"></asp:TextBox>

        </div> 
    </asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's not working is because your control's generated ID is probably not #txtDate. If you want it to remain that, set it's ClientIDMode property to Static. Otherwise, use a different jquery selector.

Comment: i cahanged to  $('#txtDate').datepicker, $("#<%=txtFromDate.ClientID%>").datepicker,$('input[name=txtFromDate]').datepicker.....but no use..

Comment: Try adding a CssClass to the txtDate control and use that as the selector. I typically use something like 'date-input'. e.g. <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server" CssClass="date-input"></asp:TextBox>. Then in your document.ready call, change the selector to $('.date-input').datepicker();